# How to skip selecting child element when parent element is disabled in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a button that is disabled and it has also a child element. Now I need to skip the `disabled` button as well as its child element when the button is `disabled` but the following selector is only skipping the button element but not its child elements. So when the parent element that button is disabled along with that the child elements should be skipped for my case. The following selector should work for both the buttons below.

**Selector:**

```
//*[(@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')) and (@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time' or .//*='Add Time') and not(@disabled)]
```

**Button with child elements:**

```
<button disabled type="button" data-nw-id="Add Time" data-nw-node="ButtonTag" data-nw-file="Button">
  <span data-nw-node="span" data-nw-file="Button">Add Time</span>
</button>
```

**Button Only:**

```
<button disabled type="button" data-nw-id="Add Time" data-nw-node="ButtonTag" data-nw-file="Button">
  Add Time
</button>
```

Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is rather used to select elements not skip them.
Regarding your long XPath expression, you want to select 'enabled' element which contains specific attributes. Child of these elements must be unselected.

Your XPath expression works correctly since the button nor the child element of the button are selected.

You can use an axis predicate to build a "safer" XPath (I've cleaned the expression a bit) :

```
//*[not(parent::*[@disabled]) and not(@disabled)][@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')][@*='Add Time' or text()='Add Time']
```

This will select only "enabled" elements with specific attributes and for which their parent not contain a `@disabled` attribute.

Comment: First of all thanks @E.Wiest for the nice answer I update my question a little bit though your answer is working in both scenarios but would you please see it again

Comment: I tried the following one but it's working for one scenario:
//*[(@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')) and (@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time') and (not(@disabled) and .//*[not(*)])]

Comment: I don't understand your EDIT. Since my answer works for both scenarios, what do you want more ? I see `.//*[not(*)])]` in your new XPath expression. What's the idea behind it ? Select button elements with specific attributes and no descendants which share the same name ?

Comment: If you want to select enabled button elements with specific attributes and no childs, you can use (keeping the structure of your XPath) (remove the `()` and add brackets) : `//*[@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')][@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time'][not(@disabled)][count(./*)=0]`

Comment: I just forgot to add `or .//*='Add Time'` this portion with the selector and just updated the question

Comment: `.//*='Add Time'` is not a valid predicate. You can use : `//*[@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')][@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or you can write : @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time' or .//*[.="Add Time"]][not(@disabled)]` or `//*/descendant-or-self::*[@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')][@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time'][not(@disabled)]`

Comment: I'm gonna post it your answer in the last comment cause I really love it @E.Wiest

Answer (score 0):

I really love this answer and grab it from the last comment of @E.Wiest. I wish to post it for other people.

```
//*[@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')][@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time' or .//*[.="Add Time"]][not(@disabled)]
```

Or

```
//*/descendant-or-self::*[@type='button' or @type='submit' or contains(@class,'btn') or contains(@class,'Button')][@data-nw-id='Add Time' or text()='Add Time' or @value='Add Time' or @title='Add Time'][not(@disabled)]
```